# Kendo MVC Grid 8th column disables MinScreenWidth property on other columns

Tags: kendo-grid, google-chrome-devtools, kendo-asp.net-mvc

Here is my columns binding for grid

```
.Columns(columns =>
{
    columns.Bound(c => c.Code);
    columns.Bound(c => c.Value).MinScreenWidth(768);
    columns.Bound(c => c.MinValue).MinScreenWidth(768);
    columns.Bound(c => c.Type).MinScreenWidth(768);
    columns.Bound(c => c.CurrencyCode).MinScreenWidth(768);
    columns.Bound(c => c.IsActive).MinScreenWidth(768);

    columns.Bound(c => c.Id).ClientTemplate("bla-bla");
})
```

The result for this config is

[image]

And if I add another column, then all responsiveness breaks

```
.Columns(columns =>
{
    columns.Bound(c => c.Code);
    columns.Bound(c => c.Value).MinScreenWidth(768);
    columns.Bound(c => c.MinValue).MinScreenWidth(768);
    columns.Bound(c => c.Type).MinScreenWidth(768);
    columns.Bound(c => c.CurrencyCode).MinScreenWidth(768);
    columns.Bound(c => c.IsActive).MinScreenWidth(768);
    columns.Bound(c => c.IsInfinite).MinScreenWidth(768); //extra column

    columns.Bound(c => c.Id).ClientTemplate("bla-bla");
})
```

[image]

Is there any reason why is it hiding? And is there any workaround except manual display/hide?

UPDATE 2019-02-15:

One more interesting fact I did not notice before: this happens only in Google Chrome DevTools device. I was trying to reproduce it again, but it works ok if you resize normal window to mobile width, if I enable any device in DevTools (e.g. Galaxy S5) then it breaks. 
Regarding names, I can't say it is one column in model that breaks grid, and there is weak correlation. Few tests (note: all columns except Code have `.MinScreenWidth(768)`:

- 1 Code column + 9 Value columns => only Code is displayed;
- 1 Code column + 9 CurrencyCode columns => grid is broken;
- 1 Code column + 8 Value columns + 1 CurrencyCode column => only Code is displayed;
- 1 Code column + 8 Value columns + 9 CurrencyCode column => grid is
  broken.

Comment: Strange. Are you positive the issue happens when adding one more column? If you use a different column besides `IsInfinite` do you get the same results?

Comment: @Supersnake please check latest update on question. this issue is not that important for me since it can be reproduced only in Google Chrome DevTools devices, but it looks kinda interesting